# CultureInfo InvariantCulture necessary?

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo

I have added one localisation for my resource file. ResGeneral.resx and ResGeneral.cs.resx. My computer has czech environment so even Invariant culture uses the .cs.resx file. The projects default culture is set to Invariant.

Then I added a combo box with options loaded from the SupportedLanguages enum, which changes the selected lang index in config, so next time program is launched, the culture is changed to the selected index.

```
public enum SupportedLanguages
    {
        Invariant = 0,
        English,
        Czech
    }

public static void ChangeLang(int lang)
    {
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        switch (lang)
        {
            case 1:
                cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en");
                break;
            case 2:
                cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("cs");
                break;
        }

        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    }
```

How should I approach this?

- Can I specify that the clean .resx (en) is to be used with invariant always?
- Is there reason to even use Invariant or can I set the default to "en"? Project owner fears that some machines might not have "en" culture installed, but I haven't found any info about that. Is that possible?
- Is this even a problem? So what it auto uses Czech, if a German user launches it, I dont have a .de file, it uses the clean .resx and he sees english

What do you think? Thanks for answers.

Comment: What kind project it's? WPF, Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Console Application launching a XNA GameWindow. So switching languages requires a restart.